# Bayesian Estimation and Multivariate Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, bayesian, least-squares, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Please help me understand a step to calculate the mean $\mu$ of this distribution.

Setting:

- $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$ are independent given the pair $\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}\right)$
- $Y_{i}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} X_{i}+\epsilon_{i}$, where each $\epsilon_{i}$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1 / \tau)$ (which has variance $\left.1 / \tau\right)$
- the $X_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ are deterministic.
  We will think of $\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}$ and $\tau$ as being random variables.
  Suppose that we place an improper prior on $\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \tau\right)$ :
  $$
  \pi\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \tau\right)=1 / \tau
  $$
  Since this expression on the right hand side does not depend on the $\beta$ 's, we may take the conditional distribution $\pi\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1} \mid \tau\right)$ to be the "uniform" improper prior: $\pi\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1} \mid \tau\right)=1$.

Answer the following problems given these assumptions. As a reminder, we let $\mathbb{X}$ be the design matrix, where the $i$ th row is the row vector $\left(1, X_{i}\right)$, and let $\mathbf{Y}$ be the column vector $\left(\begin{array}{c}Y_{1} \\ \vdots \\ Y_{n}\end{array}\right)$.
Observe that if $\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}$ and $\tau$ are given, then each $Y_{i}$ is a gaussian: $Y_{i} \mid\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \tau\right) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\beta_{0}+\beta_{1} X_{i}, 1 / \tau\right)$
Therefore, the likelihood function of the vector $\left(Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}\right)$ given $\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}, \tau\right)$ is of the form
$$
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi / \tau}}\right)^{n} \exp \left(-\frac{\tau}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i}-\beta_{0}-\beta_{1} X_{i}\right)^{2}\right)
$$
It turns out that the distribution of $\left(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1}\right)$ given $\tau$ and $Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}$ is a 2-dimensional Gaussian. In terms of $\mathbb{X}, \mathbf{Y}$ and $\tau$, what is its mean and covariance matrix?

My work thus far:
[image]

Kindly help me figuring out $\mu$! I am having a lot of problems here. Please be as details as you would to a small child, or a golden retriever!

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Sorry about that! Is it hard to read?

Comment: It's not only that: pictures don't render on some devices, they cannot be searched, and they're not text-reader-friendly.

Comment: Good point! That was exported from my tablet btw... I got close to an answer but not quite... I have an hanging $x$ term there :(

Comment: Please also note only my work is a picture. The problem statement is not. I also know the solution because the MLE is the LSE if the covariance matrix is invertible, and it is. Also the distribution must be a Gaussian so the max is the mean, another way of seeing it. However, to clarify, I was looking so an algebraic way of solving this, using this pattern matching similarly to what was done with the covariance matrix (easier). But I got really confused pattern matching the \mu :( Please help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

$(X-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)= X^T \Sigma^{-1} X - 2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}X + constant$

Comparing the equations, we will have

$\tau Y^TX = \mu^T\Sigma^{-1} \implies \mu^T = Y^TX(X^TX)^{-1} \implies \mu = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$

which is the usualy OLS result.